# Expected primary expression and Experimental ABI Encoder

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I decided to learn Solidity and have been following a tutorial. I have followed everything but when I compile I get "TypeError: This type is only supported in the new experimental ABI encoder. Use "pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;" to enable the feature.
function getListing(uint listingId) public view returns (Listing memory){" as an error.

When I commented out this error I got "ParserError: Expected primary expression.
payable(listing.seller).transfer(listing.price);"

Everything compiles fine after this.

I have tried looking for an answer but couldn't find one.

Code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0;

import "./IERC721.sol";

contract Market {
    // Public -Anyone can call
    // Private - Only the contract in is made in
    // Internal - Only This contract and inheriting contracts
    // External - Only external calls

    enum ListingStatus {
        Active,
        Sold,
        Cancelled
    }

    struct Listing{
        ListingStatus status;
        address seller;
        address token;
        uint TokenId;
        uint price;
    }

    event Listed(
        uint listingId,
        address seller,
        address token,
        uint tokenId,
        uint price
    );

    event Sale(
        uint listingId,
        address buyer,
        address token,
        uint TokenId,
        uint price
    );

    event Cancel(
        uint listingId,
        address seller
    );

    uint private _listingId = 0;
    mapping(uint => Listing) private _listings;

    function listToken(address token, uint TokenId, uint price) external {
        IERC721(token).TransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), TokenId);

        Listing memory listing = Listing(
            ListingStatus.Active,
            msg.sender,
            token,
            TokenId,
            price
        );

        

    _listingId++;

    _listings[_listingId] = listing;

    emit Listed(
        _listingId,
        msg.sender,
        token,
        TokenId,
        price
    );

    }

    // Function can read and write
    // View - Can read not write
    // Pure - no read, no write

    function getListing(uint listingId) public view returns (Listing memory){
        return _listings[listingId];
    }

    function buyToken(uint listingId) external payable{
        Listing storage listing = _listings[listingId];

        require(msg.sender != listing.seller, "Seller cannot be the buyer");
        require(listing.status == ListingStatus.Active);

        require(msg.value >= listing.price, "Insufficient Funds");
        // wei - eth but smaller

        listing.status = ListingStatus.Sold;

        IERC721(listing.token).TransferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, listing.TokenId);
        payable(listing.seller).transfer(listing.price);

        emit Sale(
            listingId,
            msg.sender,
            listing.token,
            listing.TokenId,
            listing.price
        );
    }

    function cancel(uint listingId) public {
        Listing storage listing = _listings[listingId];

        require(msg.sender == listing.seller, "Only the seller may cancel this listing");
        require(listing.status == ListingStatus.Active, "Listing is not active");

        listing.status = ListingStatus.Cancelled;

        IERC721(listing.token).TransferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, listing.TokenId);

        emit Cancel(listingId, listing.seller);
    }

}
```

If it's any help I am also using Truffle V5.0.5

Comment: Have you tried adding `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2` at the top? [This answer here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/58698/typeerror-this-type-is-only-supported-in-the-new-experimental-abi-encoder/58715) explains why it's needed.

Comment: I haven't because I don't want to be running my code on an experimental compiler. I will try it but I would still like to find a fix for a stable compiler

Comment: Using the experimental compiler gets rid of the Listing memory error but not the Expected Primary Expression

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).